# PHP ODBC_connect with existing ODBC drivers

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, odbc, sqlanywhere

I have an ODBC Connection that works:

```
$cqmconn = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
Server=JOHN-HP;
Database=cqmla;", "sa", "sa") or die ("Unable to connect to CQM site.");
```

However, I have an existing ODBC Driver called "cqm2" that connects to cqmla, but the line beow does NOT make a connection:

```
$cqmconn = odbc_connect("cqm2","sa","sa") or die ("Unable to connect to CQM site.");
```

I can, however, use that ODBC connection (and credentials) with other software and it works fine.  What am I missing?

I ask this because while I certainly can use the first method here, I have ANOTHER proprietary system that I cannot get to work, although it does have an ODBC connection I can access via other software using the: `$cqmconn = odbc_connect("cqm2","sa","sa")` format.  If I can get my existing connection to work here, I figure I should then be able to call the other one.

What am I missing?

PS:  I've tried adding SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC to the end of the call, but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**Answering my own question:**
It seems that `odbc_connect()` for PHP does NOT recognize User DSNs, only System DSNs.  As a result, when I changed the DSN I was trying to use for a connection to a System DSN, I was able to use the: `$cqmconn = odbc_connect("cqm2","sa","sa")` paradigm.